# Longdouble(1e3000) becomes inf: What can I do?

Tags: python, long-double

(Most other related questions in the web concern conversion between C's longdouble and python's. This question is different.)

I do  not see why I cannot correctly get a longdouble in python like this:

```
In [72]: import numpy as np

In [73]: np.longdouble(1e3000)
Out[73]: inf
```

It seems that I need to let my python console know 1e3000 is a longdouble instead of double. How can I do that

Comment: I would have expected `np.longdouble("1e3000")` to work, but I'm getting `inf` there as well.

Comment: Me too, same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that by using an expression like `...(1e3000)`, the Python parser has to calculate what is inside the parentheses first, and pass the result to the function call. Long double is not a native type, therefore, the value inside the parentheses is `inf` - which is passed to the longdouble constructor.  The fact the string version fails could maybe be considered a bug in NumPy - it indicates the string is converted to a Python float (which is a "float64" or "double" in C) internally, possibly using the normal Python float constructor.

The workaround is to build the long double object first, with a value that is compatble with a Python float, and them multiply it to get to the desired value. If you need to do that with several values, use a NumPy array instead of a single value:

```
>>> x = np.longdouble(10)
>>> x
10.0
>>> x **= 3000
>>> x
9.9999999999999999999e+2999
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have "long doubles".  By using scientific notation, you are making a float literal.  Those cannot represent 1e3000, so you get inf.  If you use integers, you might be able to do what you need:  10**3000.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this anwer is (partially) wrong. Please try this at console:  np.longdouble(10**700)
 ==> OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float

Comment: @Gio: On my platform, `numpy.finfo(numpy.longdouble)` claims a maximum supported value of `1.18973149536e+4932` and I'm also seeing `inf`.

Comment: @Gio A double doesn't separate the fractional and integer parts - it separates the fractional part from the exponent. A double has the form `1.M * 2^E`, where `M` and `E` (in addition to the sign bit) are stored in the double. That mans you don't need 2326 bits to store (an approximation of) 10**700, you just need enough bits in the exponent part to store the number 2325.